# Fetch non deleted documents from couch-db changes continuous feed

Tags: java, couchdb

I am looking for a way to fetch the contitious feed of non deleted documents from CouchDB.

Lightcouch jar has the continuous feed feature which I am using but it retrieves all the document including deleted one as well.

For now, I am reading all the document and added a file

```
Changes changes = dbClient.changes()
    .includeDocs(true)
    .since(0)
    .heartBeat(1000)
    .continuousChanges();
```

I found a workaround to read all and filter out the deleted one but it seems like not the best way to do it.

```
        Flux
            .interval(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            .map(intervalTicking -> changes)
            .filter(Changes::hasNext)
            .map(Changes::next)
            .filter(row -> !row.isDeleted())
            ...
```

Please suggest if there are any better options.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a filter on the _changes to filter directly at the CouchDB level. You could use a mango filter to filter _deleted:true document only.

Comment: Thanks, Alexis, filter in CouchDB worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to filter non deleted documents from changes feed, you should define a filter in an design document in your database, like the following one, where the filter "active-doc" is defined.

```
{
  "_id": "_design/filters",
  "language": "javascript",
  "filters": {
    "active-doc": "function(doc, req){\n return (!doc._deleted);\n}\n"
  }
}
```

In LightCouch you can include the filter in your changes feed configuration.

```
Changes changes = dbClient.changes()
    .includeDocs(true)
    .since(0)
    .heartBeat(1000)
    .filter("filters/active-doc")
    .continuousChanges();
```

Now you should receive only change events form non deleted documents.

As an alternative, you can use a this [fork](https://github.com/IndabaConsultores/LightCouch) of LightCouch where mango selectors are supported for the changes feed. With the fork you don't need to create a desing document in the database, just specify the selector in your client.

```
Changes changes = dbClient.changes()
    .includeDocs(true)
    .since(0)
    .heartBeat(1000)
    .selector("{\"selector\": { \"_deleted\": {\"$exists\":  false}}}")
    .continuousChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you @Juanjo for the brief examples. It helped a lot.